# Add extra documentation to rspec output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So, while I like Cucumber for its readability for integration testing and its ability to give us documentation we can share with the client easily, I also find it cumbersome from the development and testing speed standpoints.

I got to thinking today that if I could just print out messages to the RSpec documentation format that documented the "steps", then I could easily replicate the business features of Gherkin but in the simplicity of RSpec.  But I can't figure out a way to do this.

What I want is to take something like this:

```
describe "Login and Authorization Tests" do
  before (:each) do
    docs "Given I have a user"
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  it "A user can belong to one or more user roles" do
    docs "And the user has no roles assigned"
    @user.roles.length.should eq 0
    docs "When I add two roles"
    @user.roles << FactoryGirl.create(:role)
    @user.roles << FactoryGirl.create(:role)

    @user.reload
    docs "Then the user should have two roles assigned"
    @user.roles.length.should eq 2        
  end
end
```

and get this in the documentation

```
User
  Login and Authorization Tests
    A user can belong to one or more user roles
      Given I have a user
      And the user has no roles assigned"
      When I add two roles
      Then the user should have two roles assigned
```

Note that the message from "before" shows up in the docs too, and would show up with that line in every test below it.

I'm thinking of forking to see if I can add something like this in, but before I did that, does anyone know if something like this is possible already?

Comment: I am just thinking exactly the same thing! Have you made some progress with this goal? I'm currently using [Capybara 2.0 feature-DSL](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) to format my acceptance specs more like features, but I really want what you showed in your question!

Comment: Thanks @softRli for reminding me.  I posted an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also contacted the RSpec dev team and someone there posted this add-on called rspec-longrun that could be repurposed for this.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but it looks very promising.  And as a bonus, it includes timing information.

rspec-longrun: https://github.com/mdub/rspec-longrun

Thread on rspec-dev: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-dev/issues/34

Comment: Ooh! `rspec-longrun` is exactly what I've been looking for! I was just about to post a question but now I wont. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Steak](https://github.com/cavalle/steak), but the difference is not that big.
Or you can try Cucumber with RSpec matchers. In last case, you can fork RSpec and add a new [formatter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/tree/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters)

Comment: Well, instead of Steak which is a scam, you can use Capybara which provides a feature-approach to RSpec (with aliases like `feature`, `background`, `scenario`). Not much, but a first step, and exactly what Steak does. Probably the best way is to write a new formatter, thanks for pointing that.